# Granting Account Login Access using Apex

Tags: apex, api, access, lma, grant-login-access

Is there a way to **Grant Account Login Acces** using **Apex**? Not through the UI as shown in the screenshot from below. Maybe something using the Tooling API? Or Metadata API?

Thank you in advance!

[image: Grant Account Login Access screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no API for granting login access. It must be done by using the user interface. Technically, you could use a [Headless Browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser), but this is not an official API, it would be the same as using the UI.